# Network fails with 802.3ad after connecting second cable

Tags: network-interface, bonding, lacp

I'm trying to setup Bonding in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. I've got the onboard NIC plus a PCI card with two more NICs.
All three ports should get connected to a Ubiquiti Switch US-8-60W, the three ports are already configured as Aggregate ports (which should support 802.3ad).

My configuration in /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3
bond-slaves enp0s31f6 enp6s0 enp7s0
```

If only one cable is connected to enp0s31f6 (the onboard NIC), everything works correctly*. As soon as I connect a second cable, the network starts failing after half a minute or so. A bit hard to describe, sometimes I can't access the internet anymore but can still ping the router, sometimes pinging the router doesn't work either. In all cases, I can't reach the machine 192.168.1.11 from any other machine anymore.

As soon as I disconnect the second port, everything goes back to normal.

* When I say "correctly", one thing is still odd when using one cable only. I've got a few virtual machines (Virtualbox) with static IPs and bridging mode. If I select bond0 as network adapter, I can't reach the virtual machines from outside (traffic from the VM works). When I switch the adapter to enp0s31f6, I can reach the VM again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a faulty NIC!

Was a new card, but somehow the ports switched between up / down all the time.
I replaced it with another card, and the configuration above works without any problems!

Only thing I had to change was setting `bond-xmit-hash-policy` to `layer2`.